# How to add widget area above secondary sidebar and in line with primary, genesis framework

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, hook, genesis

Hi there I'm using Wordpress, and the Genesis Framework and a Child Theme.

I would like to move the slider above the secondary sidebar (the one on the left) but still in line with the primary sidebar one of the right.

I believe I either have to make a widget area or a hook in the functions.php and I have been searching google for hours but I can't find what I'm looking for, only to create a widget area above all content.

As you tell I'm new and this so please have patience with me and I appreciate any help :)

http://themetesting.casper-creations.com/

Answer (score 1):

First if you have any problem using genesis theme, you visit this [anthonycarbon.com](https://www.anthonycarbon.com/) site this will help you a lot. For the codes you have looking for is below.

```
remove_action( 'genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap', 'genesis_get_sidebar_alt' ); 
add_action( 'genesis_after_content', 'genesis_get_sidebar_alt_top', 1, 1 );
add_action( 'genesis_after_content', 'genesis_get_sidebar_alt', 1, 2 );

function genesis_get_sidebar_alt_top(){
 // your codes
}
```